# Sql query over SSH not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ssh

I'm facing a problem which is driving me real crazy, i've been looking for a solution but my finite knowledge about php is not enough to solve it, so here we go, hope you can help me.

I am generating a query via PHP which is the following one :

```
CREATE USER 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; 
GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wally\_%` . * TO 'wally'@'localhost'; 
CREATE USER 'wally'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wally\_%` . * TO 'wally'@'%'; 
CREATE DATABASE wally_foro; 
CREATE DATABASE wally_foro2;
```

When i run it on my phpmyadmin it works flawless, but when i enter this query into a ssh command and sent it :

```
mysql -uMYUSERHERE -pMYPASSWORDHERE  -e "CREATE USER 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wally\_%` . * TO 'wally'@'localhost'; CREATE USER 'wally'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `wally\_%` . * TO 'wally'@'%'; CREATE DATABASE wally_foro; CREATE DATABASE wally_foro2;"
```

It just gives me an error:

*ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* TO 'wally'@'localhost'' at line 1*

I need it to be a ssh connection but i do not figure out how to make it work. Why is it exiting an error via line command and not in phpmyadmin if it is supposed i cant use directly the script on command line. Am i wrong ?

Thank you, really appreciate you support !

---

Thank you for the support.So far i got this :

```
mysql -uMYUSER -pMYPASS  -e "CREATE DATABASE wally_foro; CREATE DATABASE wally_foro2; CREATE USER 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ``wally\\\_\%`` . * TO 'wally'@'localhost'; CREATE USER 'wally'@'\%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123'; GRANT USAGE ON * . * TO 'wally'@'\%' IDENTIFIED BY 'wally123' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ``wally\\\_\%`` . * TO 'wally'@'\%'; "
```

Now it does create localhost user and also databases, but not external user which i think might be involved with symbol % , i tried to scape it, and duplicate it, but still not working .

Thank you !

Comment: have you tried input each command seperately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I need to run more than 1-2 SQLs on a command line, I usually put it all in a text file then run it through:

```
mysql -uMYUSER -pMYPASS < /path/to/my/file
```

It is also useful when there are specific characters (foreign alphabet UTF-8 encoded).

Comment: I've been looking for that very command for days literally... since my first idea was to create a file with printf which record variables in order to make an script and being able to upload it directly to the mysql server but i did not manage to upload a file in a single line ... this just happens to beginners like me. I really really thank you for that ! SOLVED :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the singlequotes??

```
"CREATE USER \'wally\'@\'localhost.....
```

Comment: Thank you, it did help indeed !, but i still not reaching the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

The backticks are the problem: They are a shell character and being evaluated *BEFORE* the SSH commandline connects to the remote server. You should escape each one with a backslash.

Comment: Thank you ! I feel close to the solution thats to you and Lordblacksuca.

Already done that ( as well as single quotes ) but now i do get this error :


-bash: command substitution: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
-bash: command substitution: line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ERROR at line 1: Unknown command '\''.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the double quotes around the entire string with single quotes and then place backslashes before each inner single quote -- or -- switch your quoting around, using the `"` double quote around all of the quoted arguments, and `'` single quotes around the entire string you want MySQL to execute.

The double quote is a "weaker" quote character than a single quote, and the shell will still try to interpret certain characters when they are enclosed in double quotes... but not single quotes.

See [this DBA.se answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48778/mysqladmin-not-taking-inline-password/48816#48816) for more detail on what's happening here.

Comment: It did also work! Now i have to ways to do what i want !


Thank you very very much !